# unexpected behaviour with FILTER on xsd:date

Tags: xsd, sparql, virtuoso

How can I filter the count of a result (occurrences of strikes) to a particular year (1970)? My solution provides unexpected results. In the query I have written down alternatives I tried and their outcome.

Solutions mentioned by others ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795902/filtering-sparql-results-by-day-and-month), [[2]](https://pablomendes.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/sparql-xsddate-weirdness/)) did not solve the issue.

The endpoint is:
  https://api.druid.datalegend.net/datasets/rlzijdeman/ClariahTech2017/containers/clariahTech2017/sparql

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX gg: <http://www.gemeentegeschiedenis.nl/gg-schema#>
PREFIX strikes: <https://iisg.amsterdam/vocab/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?muni ?sdate (COUNT(?muni) as ?muniCount)  
WHERE {
  ?strike strikes:place ?splace .
  ?strike strikes:date ?sdate .
  ?muni rdf:type gg:Municipality .
  ?muni rdfs:label ?ggplace . 
  FILTER regex(?splace, ?ggplace)

  ### TASK: Filter results above to strikes in 1970 only

  # solution 1: extract year and FILTER on 1970
  # FILTER ( year(?sdate) = 1970 )
  ### Virtuoso 22003 Error SR586: Incomplete RDF box as argument 0 for year().

  # solution 2: filter on ?sdate
  # FILTER ( ?sdate >= '1970-01-01'^^xsd:date && ?sdate <= '1970-12-31'^^xsd:date )
  ### Virtuoso 2201B Error SR098: regexp error at '? [Arnhem ( Gelderland )]' column 0 (nothing to repeat)
  ####### Why? This was no problem under solution 1 ?!
  ####### Also: note that each of these works seperately, but not together(!):
  # FILTER ( ?sdate >= '1970-01-01'^^xsd:date )
  # FILTER ( ?sdate <= '1970-12-31'^^xsd:date )

} 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regarding "Solution 1":

The function `year` takes as input a literal of type `xsd:dateTime` - your data only contains `xsd:date` and `xsd:gYearMonth` literals. That'S why the cast probably fails.

#### Regarding "Solution 2":

Maybe a bug in Virtuoso. But in general, I'm not sure why you need REGEX here. If you just want to get rid of the language tags for comparison, use `str` function. It's also much faster:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX gg: <http://www.gemeentegeschiedenis.nl/gg-schema#>
PREFIX strikes: <https://iisg.amsterdam/vocab/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT * {
  ?strike strikes:place ?splace .
  ?strike strikes:date ?sdate .
  ?muni rdf:type gg:Municipality .
  ?muni rdfs:label ?ggplace . 
  FILTER (?sdate >= '1970-01-01'^^xsd:date && ?sdate < '1971-01-01'^^xsd:date)
  FILTER(str(?splace) = str(?ggplace)) 
} 
LIMIT 10
```

Another thing that I find strange in your query, shouldn't you count the strikes instead of the municipality itself? I mean, as far as I understand, you want to get the number of strikes per municipality for a particular date( correct me if I'm wrong). If so, the query should look like this:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX gg: <http://www.gemeentegeschiedenis.nl/gg-schema#>
PREFIX strikes: <https://iisg.amsterdam/vocab/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?muni (COUNT(?strike) as ?strikes) {
  ?strike strikes:place ?splace .
  ?strike strikes:date ?sdate .
  ?muni rdf:type gg:Municipality .
  ?muni rdfs:label ?ggplace . 
  FILTER (?sdate >= '1970-01-01'^^xsd:date && ?sdate < '1971-01-01'^^xsd:date)
  FILTER(str(?splace) = str(?ggplace)) 
} 
GROUP BY ?muni
LIMIT 10
```

In addition, getting the `?sdate` doesn't make sense if there are multiple strikes, right? Unless you want to get the dates of all strikes like this:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX gg: <http://www.gemeentegeschiedenis.nl/gg-schema#>
PREFIX strikes: <https://iisg.amsterdam/vocab/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?muni (COUNT(?strike) as ?strikes) (GROUP_CONCAT(?sdate; separator = ";") as ?s_dates) {
  ?strike strikes:place ?splace .
  ?strike strikes:date ?sdate .
  ?muni rdf:type gg:Municipality .
  ?muni rdfs:label ?ggplace . 
  FILTER (?sdate >= '1970-01-01'^^xsd:date && ?sdate < '1971-01-01'^^xsd:date)
  FILTER(str(?splace) = str(?ggplace)) 
} 
GROUP BY ?muni
LIMIT 10
```

#### Minor comment

I also tried to cast to `xsd:dateTime` first and then select the `year`:

```
FILTER (year(xsd:dateTime(?sdate)) = 1970)
```

Funnily, this failed because of 29.2. :D :

```
Virtuoso 22007 Error DT006: Cannot convert 1911-02-29 to datetime : Too many days (29, the month has only 28)
```

Not sure, if the value 28 for February is hardcoded in Virtuoso, or whether it's bound to leap years - at least this would make sense as 1911 wasn't a leap year (1911 is not divisible by 4, thus, it's a common year)

Comment: I know, I shouldn't do this: but thank you very much: your answer is complete it helps me to understand so much more than just this problem.

Comment: *Maybe a bug in Virtuoso.* — I think the reason is that brackets are not escaped when `REGEX(?splace, ?ggplace)` is evaluated to `REGEX("Arnhem (Gelderland)", "Arnhem (Gelderland)")` or something like. Also, it seems that @Richard uses `REGEX` because values of `strikes:place` are not equal to municipalities labels sometime. Probably he could use `STRSTARTS`, but of course, this should be a problem of the endpoint maintainer to make values of `strikes:place` things instead of strings, not forcing users to perform these fuzzy joins...

Comment: The question is why the query doesn't fail without the date filter. Even removing the LIMIT and having a timeout of 0 doesn't lead to this exception.

Comment: Regarding the place matching you might be right. I just tried to find a workaround. But in general, I don't think that it makes sense to use something besides exact match here - and even that's no guarantee for correct results. Have a look at the following query:

Comment: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX gg: <http://www.gemeentegeschiedenis.nl/gg-schema#>
PREFIX strikes: <https://iisg.amsterdam/vocab/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT distinct ?muni ?splace {
  ?strike strikes:place ?splace .
  
  ?muni rdf:type gg:Municipality .
  ?muni rdfs:label ?ggplace . 
  FILTER (strstarts(str(?splace), str(?ggplace))) 
FILTER (str(?splace) != str(?ggplace)) 
} 
limit 10`

Comment: It shows that substring matching will lead to wrong results.

Comment: @AKSW IMO it's rather lame that you have to do `year(xsd:dateTime(?gYearMonth))`.  `xsd:gYearMonth` maps onto the same value space as `xsd:dateTime` (together with several other XML Schema datatypes), so it must be trivial for SPARQL implementors to allow `year(?gYearMonth)` directly.  I guess there was some standardization reason for this, maybe XPath functions do not support overloading, or some other historic reason?